# Understanding principal value integral

Tags: improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral, cauchy-principal-value

I'm reading the original article on distance covariance ([link](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1201012979)), and throughout the article the author uses the following lemma:

[image]

Can someone please explain what he actually means by "principal value sense". If we use the limit of integrals over increasing annulus, then with $A_\varepsilon= \mathbb{R}^d \setminus (B(0,\varepsilon)\cup B(0,1/\varepsilon)^c)$ we easily see that
$$
0\leq 1_{A_\varepsilon}(t) \frac{1-\cos(t^\intercal x)}{\|t\|^{d+\alpha}} \uparrow 1_{\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\}}(t) \frac{1-\cos(t^\intercal x)}{\|t\|^{d+\alpha}} ,
$$
when $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$ (does not make sense for negative $\varepsilon$), for any $t\in\mathbb{R}^d$. Thus Lebesgue's monotone convergence theorem yields that
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d \setminus A_\varepsilon} \frac{1-\cos(t^\intercal x)}{\|t\|^{d+\alpha}} \, d\lambda^d(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\}} \frac{1-\cos(t^\intercal x)}{\|t\|^{d+\alpha}} \, d\lambda^d(t),
$$
so I'm wondering why they haven't just stated the lemma in terms of this integral.

I obviously haven't understood the term “principal value sense” correctly.

Can anyone please provide me with the correct interpretation of the integral in the lemma?

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:undergraduate-research] tag. It is being removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. This integral converges, so the principle value is unnecessary.  However, if you want to consider

\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \frac{1-\exp(i\left<t,x\right>)}{\|t\|^{d+\alpha}}dt
\end{equation*}

for $\alpha>1$, then you need the principal value.  Notice that

\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d\backslash A_{\epsilon}} \frac{\sin(\left<t,x\right>)}{\|t\|^{d+\alpha}}dt
\end{equation*}

is zero for every $\epsilon>0$ since the integrand is odd. Therefore the limit as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ exists, even though the function is not Lebesgue integrable.